# What is the correct way to say? "Do you see my screen" or "can you see my screen"?

Tags: grammar

What is the correct way to say?

"Do you see my screen" or "can you see my screen"?

Comment: Either is correct.  The first is probably a hair more likely to satisfy prescriptivists.

Comment: Perfect one : Are you able to see my screen?

Answer (score 2):

I would say it's "six of one and half a dozen of the other". Perhaps you could argue that "can you see" suggests a technical problem (troubleshooting by video link?) whereas "do you see?" suggests that you might not even have been looking until asked the question, but this does not amount to either being *wrong*.